# How do I add a custom view to a layout programatically Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to implement a custom view into a `LinearLayout` that's inside of a `ScrollLayout`, but I don't know how many views I'll implement into the `LinearLayout`. What I want is like a scrolling box of interactive cards. How can I do this?

Comment: You can add as many views in a LinearLayout but this is bad practice to do so. recyclerview is best for this use case. if you want to add different type of view then it also can manage in recyclerview with multiple layout

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is like a scrolling box of interactive cards.

Use `RecyclerView` instead of `LinearLayout`.

Comment: How would I go about doing this, I can't find anything about using custom views in a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @Phishy1 I suggest starting with RecyclerView basics.